# duplicated values in print()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can anyone tell me why im getting duplicated values when I print the results of this list?

```py
degrees_values = [0, 5.85, -2.5]
kelvin_values = []
for degrees in degrees_values:
    kelvin = degrees + 273.15
    kelvin_values = kelvin_values + [kelvin]
    print(kelvin_values)
```

I've tried printing the list length, just 'kelvin' but this isn't the result I'm after. I'm consantly seeing this:

```
[273.15]
[273.15, 279.0]
[273.15, 279.0, 270.65]
```

when im looking for just:

```
[273.15, 279.0, 270.65]
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: `kelvin_values = [d + 273.15 for d in degrees_values]`

Comment: The "print" is in the for-loop and is repeated in each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `print` statement out of the `for` loop block as such:

```py
degrees_values = [0, 5.85, -2.5]
kelvin_values = []
for degrees in degrees_values:
    kelvin = degrees + 273.15
    kelvin_values = kelvin_values + [kelvin]
print(kelvin_values)
```

When you put the `print` inside the block, each iteration you print `kelvin_values` and it "spams" your console..

Answer (score 0):

This is an indentation problem.
It seems like you did not paste your code correctly in StackOverflow, but I assume that it looks like this :

```py
degrees_values = [0, 5.85, -2.5]
kelvin_values = []
for degrees in degrees_values:
    kelvin = degrees + 273.15
    kelvin_values = kelvin_values + [kelvin]
    print(kelvin_values)
```

What you are seeing is the list being built, because there is a print statement in each iteration.
I suggest you move the print statement out of the for loop so you only see the final result :

```py
degrees_values = [0, 5.85, -2.5]
kelvin_values = []
for degrees in degrees_values:
    kelvin = degrees + 273.15
    kelvin_values = kelvin_values + [kelvin]

# I do not indent here
print(kelvin_values)
```

Moreover, it could be wiser to use the append method of the list to add values like so :

```py
degrees_values = [0, 5.85, -2.5]
kelvin_values = []
for degrees in degrees_values:
    kelvin = degrees + 273.15
    kelvin_values.append(kelvin)
print(kelvin_values)
```